# Distribution of a random segment on a string

Tags: distributions, variance, mean

I have a linear string of unit length, and I randomly sample two locations a and b from Uniform(0, 1). Then I cut the string at these two locations to get a sub-string. What is the distribution for the size of the sub-string (i.e. |a-b|)? Otherwise, I want to at least know the mean and variance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(a,b)$ constitute one draw from the uniform distribution on the unit square. The region where $|a - b| \gt x$ is a pair of equilateral right triangles, one at $(0,1)$ and the other at $(1,0)$ with side lengths $1-x$; they fit together into a square with area $(1-x)^2$.  Thus the CDF of $x = |a-b|$ equals $1 - (1-x)^2$, $0 \le x \le 1$.

[image]

A similar analysis appears in the solution to problem 43 of Fred Mosteller's *Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability* (1965).  It asks for the expected values of the smallest, middle, and largest pieces.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a snippet of Maple code that shows that the PDF of $\lvert a - b \rvert$ is $2 - 2 t$:

```
with(Statistics):
a := RandomVariable(Uniform(0,1));
b := RandomVariable(Uniform(0,1));
PDF(abs(X - Y), t) assuming 0 < t, t < 1;
```

returns $2 - 2 t$. You can see that it's true by computing the probability that $\lvert a - b \rvert < t$ by hand: it's the area of the subset of the unit square that has horizontal or vertical distance to the diagonal of at most $t$; which means that it's one minus the area of two right triangles with legs of length $1 - t$; which means that it's $1 - 2 \cdot \frac{(1 - t)^2}{2} = 1 - (1 - t)^2$. The derivative of that is $2 - 2t$.

(Disclaimer: I maintain Maple's Statistics package.)

Comment: +1 (Your answer came in while I was drawing my figure...)

Comment: @whuber: I was considering drawing a figure, but was a little too lazy. You've earned my +1 for it :)